# VBA - Hide predefined ranges using vba

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I have a relatively hard problem which i think pertains to the way i define variables and I cannot solve the issue hence the questions below. Thanks for taking the time to read through anyway.

I have sheet 1 and sheet 2

On sheet 1 a table is crated based on user selection, based on checkbox values etc. That's working fine.

I'm then looking at a certain row in sheet 1 and it's value, applying `=(int(not(isblank(cellreference))))`, this gives me a 1 if it has a value or a zero if it doesn't have a value.

I'm then summing the amount of 1s i get to give me a value. This value is added to a predefined range in sheet 2 which is the "outcome" of table in sheet 1. It's essentially printing a document but I don't want empty rows visible.

Using the received value i apply `="A"&"191"+SUM(P5:P20)&":M206"` which gives me a range A199:M206 (cell named as HideRowsGF.
I then want to use this range in sheet 2 to hide rows so my code is the below, but i cannot get it to work for

Performing and if, if the if is correct I'm calling HideRows
Hide rows below

```
Private Sub HideRows() ' Range 191 - 206
    Dim HideRowsSheet2 As String
    Set HideRowsSheet2 = SH1.Range("HideRowsGF").Value
    'SH2.Rows("HideRowsSheet2").EnireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Basically I'm using a formula to get a path on sheet 1 and trying to use the path to hide rows on sheet 2 but cannot get it to work.

Please let me know your thoughts.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry @SJR, didn't mean to ruin the continuity of your comment

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with syntax and one typo.

For the line `Set HideRowsSheet2 = SH1.Range("HideRowsGF").Value` - vba does not require a string's value to be set using the `Set` keyword.

For the line `'SH2.Rows("HideRowsSheet2").EnireRow.Hidden = True`, you have three issues - a typo with `EnireRow`, you don't refer to a string variable using quotes, and you cannot select rows in a range using the `Rows()` function.

```
Private Sub HideRows()

    Dim SH1 As Worksheet
    Set SH1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim SH2 As Worksheet
    Set SH2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim HideRowsSheet2 As String
    HideRowsSheet2 = SH1.Range("HideRowsGF").value  'named range HideRowsGF has address "A199:M206"

    SH2.Range(HideRowsSheet2).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @marcucciboy2
Thanks for your answer.

I'm getting stuck on the last row, it's giving me a range of worksheet error. I take it I'm referring a variable that doesn't exist but cannot find it.

I've written the code exactly as per your instruciton. Do you believe your instruction is 100% correct ?

Comment: Are your sheets named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"? I chose those because they are the default and your example did not specify you sheet names

Comment: @MatthewGuzik walk me more slowly through what you're seeing

Comment: I've solved this issue now thank you for the suggestions. They're much appreciated.

Comment: Could I ask what you ended up doing?

Comment: Hello,          Dim HideAluGFLines As String
                   HideAluGFLines = SHAluRads.Range("AluGFHideLines").Value
                   SHQuotation.Range(HideAluGFLines).EntireRow.Hidden = True